# Django: Filter ModelChoiceField by user

Tags: python, django

I have a model along with a ModelForm based on that model.  The ModelForm contains a ModelMultipleChoice field, which I specify in the subclass of my ModelForm:

```
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(user=user))
```

As you can see, I need to filter the Category queryset by user.  In other words, users should only see their own categories on the drop down.  But how can I do this when user, or more specifically, request.user, is not available in a Model instance?

**Edit:** Adding my subclass of the CBV:

```
class TransUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = TransactionForm
    model = Transaction
    template_name = 'trans_form.html'
    success_url='/view_trans/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TransUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = 'update'
        return context
```

I tried `form_class = TransactionForm(user=request.user)` and I'm getting a NameError saying that request was not found.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass `request.user` to form init in view:

```
def some_view(request):
     form = TransactionForm(user=request.user)
```

and add `user` parameter to form `__init__` method (or pop it from `kwargs` in form):

```
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction

    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # user = kwargs.pop('user', User.objects.get(pk_of_default_user))
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                     queryset=Category.objects.filter(user=user))
```

**update:** in class based views you can add extra parameter to form init in `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class TransUpdateView(UpdateView):
    #...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(YourView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution in the Model makes a lot of sense.  Now the question is, how would I do this using a class-based generic view?

Comment: Ok, I added that, now I get `cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`.

Comment: Yes, when adding exactly what you have but of course changing the super call to my own class name.  I am using Django 1.5 by the way.  When I try `self.request.user[0]` to narrow down the issue, I get `SimpleLazyObject does not support indexing`.

Comment: @trpt4him sorry, my error was here: `{'user', self.request.user}`, should be `{'user': self.request.user}`

Comment: Ahh, I should have seen that myself.  Ok added that, then I was getting `__init__ got unexpected keyword arg 'user'`, so I changed the `__init__` of the model subclass to `def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):`, removed the `user=kwargs.pop`, then it works!  Thanks!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45132/discussion-between-trpt4him-and-ndpu)

Comment: @ndpu, How do I give bootstrap features like 'class':'form-control' to this helpful code???

Comment: @Ptar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms