# Django - Styling a UserCreationForm with css

Tags: html, css, django

The Django `UserCreationForm` is very useful and easy to use functionally, however, it just throws everything onto the page so all the `TextField`s are in one line.

Is there anyway to layout and style the form? Specifically to put `label`s  and input fields on a new line and possibly make it possible to apply some CSS to the whole form and individual parts of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every django form has three methods:

```
as_p()
as_ul()
as_table()
```

See the [outputting forms as html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#outputting-forms-as-html) section in the docs.  You can style this output as you want.

If you want even more control over form's html then read [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#more-granular-output) of the same documentation.

Comment: so this is from 2015 and the page is not longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BoundField` and custom filters, and correct names of attributes of `UserCreationForm` class

Uses the `BoundField` class to display HTML or access attributes for a single field of a Form instance. And add CSS with a filter in the templatetags  folders with an `__init__.py`, if have error remember add templatetags in your **INSTALLED_APP** like to   `'app.name.templatetags'` like:

```
  {{ form.username.label_tag }}
  {{ form.username|addclass:'form-control' }}
  {{ form.password1.label_tag }}
  {{ form.password1|addclass:'form-control' }}
  {{ form.password2.label_tag }}
  {{ form.password2|addclass:'form-control' }}
```

View source
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py

The passwords are named 'password1' and 'password2'

Answer (score 1):

In your forms.py,you can inherit UserCreationForm and set css style.(How to set css for forms [CSS styling in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms))