# How do you add custom css to django form: form.as_p?

Tags: python, css, django

I spent some time adding some css to a input field with submit button. However, I was still only learning how to use django forms and found I had to use 'form.as_p' in my template. As a result, I lost the styling I wanted to have. What methods exist to add styling to django form elements?!

P.s. I didn't post up any of my code because it's stock standard. Just a regular template connected with form/model. Just curious about how to add the styling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS styling in Django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms) - This could help you, it's for a table but works for p as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your Django form elements are rendered with an id matching the given field name for example a form like this:

```
BasicForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
```

will get rendered with ids for each input element like first_name_id and last_name_id, you can then apply css styles using those ids, if you wish to add a class to all form fields (if you are using something like bootstrap) you can modify form field widgets like this:

```
BasicForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = models.CharField(...,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'myclass'})
    last_name = models.CharField(...,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'myfieldclass'})
```

Comment: This won't add a class to the <p> tag but will instead add class to the input text field.

Answer (score 0):

Add `form-control` css class to the widgets.

The form class is the access point of the input tags through widgets. By changing the widget attr from the constructor method in `form.Form`.

This method `self.visible_fields()` is to get all the visible field that can view in frontend.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        for field in self.visible_fields():
            field.field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```