# How to add space after label in ModelForms of django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to add space after "Mobile No: ",meaning in between label and text area. But by using django ModelForms I am not able to do that, it shows "Mobile No:" without any space between label and textarea.

This is how I have described it in models.py file.

```
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Mobile No", validators=[mobileno])
```

forms.py file

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('phone',)
```

This is the content of my html file.

```
<form method="post">    
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
       </form>
```

This is how it is showing by default.

[image]

How can I add space between label and textarea. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please post your forms.py and html file also.Then We will be able to help you.

Comment: hey @PrakharTrivedi please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout and spacing of form labels and fields is a presentation matter and best handled through CSS.

See also: [CSS styling in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms)

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate through your form fields.

Like this:

```
<form method="post" > {% csrf_token %}

        {% for field in form %}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }} : </label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in 3.1.4 you have the option to use `label='Mobile No'` and `label_suffix=': '` to edit forms.

Answer (score 0):

**forms.py file** You can add a widget with a form-control class on your forms.py file

`class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm): class Meta: model = UserInfo fields = ('phone',) widgets = { 'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), }`