# Applying bootsrap and custom css to {{form}} elements in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to apply CSS to individual {{form}} fields on my html template.
I am referencing this solved question:

[CSS styling in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms)`

using the answer I created my forms.py page as follows:

```
from django import forms
from .models import ContactInfo


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
# class meta brings in the fields from models
class Meta:
    model = ContactInfo

    # grab the fields from models ContactInfo class
    fields = ('Fullname')

    # specify which bootstrap class each html widget should take
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Fullname'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

html using {{form}} elements:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_Fullname">Full Name:</label>
  {{form.Fullname}}
</div>
```

The working html w/o usage of {{form}}:

`<div class="form-group">
     <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
  </div>`

How do I get the "label" tag to point to the id inside {{form.Fullname}}. My guess is it is not doing that right now hence it doesn't apply the css. That or the class i specified in the widgets in the forms.py is not working how I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="form-group">
{% for field in form %}
  <label for="id_Fullname" id="{{ field.name }}">Full Name:</label>
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

try this

Comment: Does not work. I must be missing something from the other solutions to this problem I see on stack overflow. Will try to do this again from scratch.

Comment: solved! my def __init__  function was inside the Class Meta instead of Class ContactForm. Nothing wrong with the solutions suggested it was an error in placing the def__init__

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`id_for_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.id_for_label) property of `field`:

> Use this property to render the ID of this field. For example, if you are manually constructing a **<label>** in your template.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="{{ form.Fullname.id_for_label }}">Full Name:</label>
  {{ form.Fullname }}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried inputing what you suggested. Same deal. Not sure if this means anything. My IDE( jetbrains/pycharm) highlights {{ form.Fullname.id_for_label }} in red mentioning unresolved id by inspecting the xml. I feel like the form.Fullname does not contain an auto created id from the ModelForm class. Will keep reading your link.

Answer (score 0):

This was an error of placing the def **init** function inside Class Meta: instead of Class ContactInfo. I had not realized I had indented it improperly.