# Django Custom Template Form and {{next}}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-registration

I'm stuck on creating form, looks like `{{ forms.as_p }}`.
I need to login to website using this form. Uing forms.as_p it everything works perfectly, but I need to create my own customized form.

Problem is, that after reading lot's of website's and documentation I still can't understand, how to create custom form with my css class and input fields.

I tried this one:

```
action="", method ="post"
                     <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                        </div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" value="Log In" />
```

But it doesn't work.
What fields, I've missed.

Also I have another question: Is it possible to custom "next" variable to redirect after login on my custom page? And how I can do it?

Comment: The HTML snippet that you've posted isn't even complete. `action="", method ="post"` by itself means nothing. Please be clearer in what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS styling in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms)

Comment: Thx helb, but I still got one question. If I create form in forms.py and customize it, how should I call this form on my webpage?

Comment: @ return your form from view's context

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie in django, still can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use your forms.py to create a form that you can use in your HTML-Code via Jinja.

Your **forms.py** could look like this:

```
from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    age = forms.IntegerField(label='Your age')
```

Then you would do some **cleaning** to make sure the data passed to the form has the right format.

```
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    if not name:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You have to type in a name.')
    return name
```

In your **views.py**:

```
def some_view(request):
      form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)

      if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            //do something with the name
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            user.username = name
            user.save()
            return redirect('to_profile_of_user')
      return render(request, 'change_profile.html', {'form':form})
```

Here it is very important that you pass the form to your template(HTML).

Your **change_profile.html**:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{form.as_p}} //That is the form you passed
  <input type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>
```

I hope my answer gives you a little bit of advice. Now you have seen a complete roundtrip. Maybe you should have a closer look at the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/). It is very helpful.

The code is written on the fly and not tested. But it is enough for an overview. You should not forget to **import the things you need**. I did not do that.

Comment: Thanks for expaining. I've the same thing as you, but without cleaning, and deleted name = form.cleaned.data.get ( still, don't understand why for is this row). But it doesn't work

Comment: `form.cleaned.data.get` is for getting the cleaned data back from your `forms.py`. What do you exactly want to know ? To know how to style your form with css ?