# How to convert html form to Django form and preserve styling?

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a pure html form which I wish to use to collect sign-in information using a Django backend.

Here is my pure non-Django html form:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Username or E-mail Address</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="pull-right" href="#">(Lost Password?)</a>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span class="remember-box checkbox">
                <label for="rememberme">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="rememberme">Remember Me
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-orange uppercase pull-right">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is what it looks like with all the styling:

[image]

In order to process this form I have created a view:

```
def login_page(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'form': form}

    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            try:
                del request.session['guest_email_id']
            except:
                pass
            if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
                return redirect(redirect_path)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print('Error')

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

I am aware that I need a form.py class which I have created and is as follows:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

How do I use this form class to render the same form as done by the html preserving the styling. Additionally, once rendered how do I submit the form data for processing to the view by using the link disguised as a button below?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-orange uppercase pull-right">Login</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS styling in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with Django, it is not possible to create an HTML form **as is** in a Form inheriting from `forms.ModelForm` or `forms.Form`. The best we can do is, assign classes to the widgets which are assigned to the specific form fields in form of `attrs`, like so:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

This will attach your CSS classes to the rendered form when you use `{{ form.as_p }}` or similar others in your template.

Then for rendering the `divs`, you unpack the form yourself, rather than letting Django do the work, like so:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{ form.username.errors }}
                <label for="{{form.username.id_for_label}}">Username or E-mail Address</label>
                {{ form.username }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{form.password.errors}}
                <a class="pull-right" href="#">(Lost Password?)</a>
                <label for="{{form.password.id_for_label}}">Password</label>
                {{form.password}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.........
```

And so on.

However, it is generally considered a bad practice to couple your design and logic, which we clearly are doing here.

References: [Django Documentation - Working With Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just one question, how do I set the id for the label used in the for attribute of the label tag?

Comment: In my experience, I don't think you can. I double-checked the documentation to be sure, and it was mentioned nowehere. If that was a priority, then in the view, I'd access the `request.POST` dict and instantiate a new `LoginForm` on my own, and then use it for validation.

Comment: However, I don't think that is necessary unless absolutely critical - If you need it in JS, then instead of separating JS code into files, write a `{% block js %}...{% endblock %}` in your `base.html` and while writing contents of this block, use `{{ form.field.id_for_label }}` as you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the POST method, you are required to use `{% csrf_token %}` else while rendering it is bound to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your pure non-django form looks a lot like Bootstrap formatting. If that's all there is to it, then you can save yourself a lot of time by using [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with one of its [Bootstrap template packs](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs)

Even if there's more to it, django-crispy-forms is much more amenable to custom formatting than raw Django is.