# Django role based form

Tags: python, django

I have two users a customer and an admin. And I have an update and a create form with a status field and other fields. The status filed displays whether the order is received, scheduled, or in manufacturing. I want only the admin to update that field and customer to only view it. Can anyone tell me how can I implement it? Thanks!

Comment: you need to share codes regarding how you are maintaining these roles

Comment: @ruddra you can have.look at it now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and ___read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try like this by overriding `OrderForm`:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not user.is_superuser:  # or do admin check
            self.fields['status_choices'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user','date']
```

Then pass the user instance through the `OrderForm` when initiating it in the view:

```
form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,initial=initial_date, user=user)
```

### Update

It might not work for intitial data because it has a choice which does not exist in the `choices` in the model field of `Order` model. Change it to:

```
initial_date = {
    'status':"Processing/Manufacturing"
}
```

You can also add it as default value in the model field as well:

```
  status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = status_choices, default="Processing/Manufacturing")
```

If you do not want to display to field at all, then you can make it hidden with:

```
if not user.is_superuser:  # or do admin check
    self.fields['status_choices'].widget.attrs['hidden'] = True
```

Or just remove it:

```
if not user.is_superuser:  # or do admin check
    self.fields.pop('status_choices')
```

Comment: it's partially working, in the status drop-down filed it's still saying the field is required

Comment: it's working fine thanks a lot. May I know what if i want to show status field only when we are logged in as admin in the form , but not if we are logged in as customer. How can we implement that ?

Comment: NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_superuser' this is the error I'm getting now

Comment: because you are not passing `user` through the `OrderForm()` in the view. Pass it like this: `OrderForm(request.POST or None, ..., user=request.user)`.

Comment: working fine , but now i cant update an order. for the update order it's giving me 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_superuser' error

Comment: please see my last comment. :)

Comment: is there any way in which u can pop or hide more than one field ?

Comment: just add another line like status_choice with new field for pop or hide

Comment: yeah i tried it's working , but i dont know how to  hide the button as well

Comment: just use a `{% if user.is_superuser %}<button></button>{% endif %}`

Comment: alright lastly what if i want to get rid of textfield border outline ?

Comment: use CSS :) I can't help you with that. But if you write custom css classes and want to add it to a form field, then check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827669/2696165