# Django form: Custom filter 'addclass' not working

Tags: python, django

I tried to use the second answer to this question: [CSS styling in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms)

I am trying to add class to inputs so I can style my form. Working with a custom filter seemed reasonable to me. The problem is, that when I run the server I get the error: *addclass requires 2 arguments, 1 provided*

This is my code:

myfilters.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='addclass')
def addclass(value, arg):
    return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': arg})
```

contact.html:

```
<form method="post">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}

            <div class="fieldWrapper">
              {{ form.nome_completo.errors }}
              {{ form.nome_completo.label_tag }}
              {{ form.nome_completo | addclass: 'form_nome-completo' }}
              <span class="helptext">{{ form.nome_completo.help_text }}</span>
            </div>

</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove spaces between the filter and the fieldname and also after the addclass filter

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt thanks it worked! But, why is it space sensitive?

Comment: That's just the way it is :)