# How can i increase the width of a drop-down field in a django form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to increase width of dropdown field in Django form, I tried both inline CSS as well as widgets, below is code I have tried

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
 {% block content %}
  <form action = "" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      **<center>Product: <h6 style="width: 350px;">{{ form.product }}</h6></center>** 
      <br>
        <center>Rules: {{ form.rule }}</center>
    <input type="submit" value=Compute>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

PRODUCTS = (
    ('hp','HP'),
    ('wipro', 'WIPRO'),
)

class InputForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        **widgets = {'product': forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:200px'})}**

    product = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PRODUCTS)
    rule = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Textarea, label="Rules")
```

[image: Click to see output]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it's better to give it a class and edit it using css

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827590/css-styling-in-django-forms

Answer (score 0):

Try to Pip install `"django-widget-tweaks"` as this will enable you to use custom css easily.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).